# Install KSQLDB on windows 10

Tags: windows, apache-kafka, ksqldb

As part of my end of study project, I will do a big data streaming project I will use apache kafka native and now I will use KSQL
my question is the following :
is there a way to install ksql without going through confluent  platform or docker i meani want install ksql directly on windows 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install it directly in WSL2, yes, via the tarball method if you don't want rest of Confluent Platform dependencies

Otherwise, you need to build the source code and run it since there are no standalone Windows executables for it

Comment: thanks but what did you mean by build the source code and run it !?

Comment: Clone the github project and run the main method like any other Java application